# How to add bookmark using MigraDoc?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, migradoc

I want to add Bookmark in my PDF using MigraDoc.

For example: two images on a single page.

```
           1. Images1
           2. Images2**
```

and the same name bookmark will generate.

If I click on `image1` bookmark that image will be shown to me. Remember both images are on single page.

Answer (score 1):

MigraDoc creates bookmarks automatically for headings.

To create bookmarks without visible text on the page, you can create headings with a font size of e.g. 0.0001 and white colour.

There is one drawback: up to PDFsharp 1.50 beta 1, these bookmarks jump to the correct page, but not the correct area on the page. So with two images on one page, the bookmarks will not work as intended by the OP.

Comment: Or you can add a bookmark to a paragraph: `paragraph.AddBookmark("Bookmark text");`

Comment: @ajeh `AddBookmark` adds a MigraDoc bookmark (that can be used for hyperlinks from one PDF page to another), but it does not add an entry to the bookmark tree shown by Adobe Reader.